# Why is this Requests and BeautifulSoup login script not working?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The following is a bit of code i produced on the back of the `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup` libraries for Python 3.

```py
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_data():
    return {'email': str(input('Enter your email.')),
        'password': str(input('Enter your password.'))}

def obtain_data():
    login_data=get_data()
    form_data={'csrf_token': login_data['email'],
               'login': '1',
               'redirect': 'account/dashboard',
               'query': None,
               'required': 'email,password',
               'email': login_data['email'],
               'password': login_data['password']}
    headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
    with rq.Session() as s:
        r=s.get('https://www.formstack.com/admin/user/login',headers=headers)
        form_data['csrf_token']+=','+bs(r.content, 'html.parser').find('input',attrs={'name':'csrf_token'})['value']
        r=s.post('https://www.formstack.com/admin/user/login',data=form_data,headers=headers)
        assert('Collect' in bs(r.content,'html.parser'))

obtain_data()
```

The purpose of the code is to log into a survey platform called [Formstack](https://www.formstack.com) using the login credentials obtained by `get_data()`. To do this, we create a session using Requests. From here, we send a get request to Formstack's login page. We assemble a parse tree of the response to this request using BeautifulSoup, and hence retrieve the value of the input HTML tag with `name='csrf_token'` (again, using BeautifulSoup), since we need this value to complete our login form. From here, we assemble a form, denoted `form_data` in the code above, and submit a post request using this form, again to Formstack's login page. This *should* log me into my Formstack account, but for some reason, it doesn't. I've checked that it doesn't by running an `assert()` line on the contents of the first page I see after logging in, and, using this method, I've always gotten an assertion error.

I'm not very well acquainted with web scraping in Python, and hence I'm not sure where to go with this problem. I've tried allowing redirects in both the get request and the post request, but I've come up short in both cases. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to mimic the browser's behavior as if the request was made from a browser. Sometimes that required headers too but here they don't seem to be required(you can still add them if you want).

Looking at the "Network" tab of my browser with "Preserve" on, i can see the order in which the requests are being made. The important part is a GET request that's being made before the actual POST request (which sends your credentials). The order seems to be important here so it is preserved.

Note 1: I've used regex here to extract the token, but you should use `BeautifulSoup` if you need to parse the page at some other time.

Note 2: The page seems to load over time with JavaScript receiving data from the dynamic back-end. Make sure to check the Network tab and see what requests are being made to get you what you need, and make those same requests in your code.

```py
import requests
import re
email = "email"
password = "pwd"
with requests.Session() as sess:
    login_page = sess.get("https://www.formstack.com/admin/user/login")
    #extract token from page source, you can use any other method for this
    token = re.search(r'token="(.*?)"', login_page.text).group(1)
    #the exact format as seen in the "Networks" tab of the browser
    data = {
    "csrf_token": token,
    "login": "1",
    "redirect": "account/dashboard",
    "query": "",
    "required": "email,password",
    "email": email,
    "password": password
    }
    GET_url = "https://www.formstack.com/admin/platform-sso/determineSsoStatus/" + email
    POST_url = "https://www.formstack.com/admin/session/create"
    #keep the order of requests as seen in the browser's Network tab
    sess.get(GET_url)
    final = sess.post(POST_url, data=data)
    #check final redirect, and see if user is taken to the dashboard or redirected back to login
    #uncomment to see where the redirects end at:
    #print(final.url)
    if "redirect" in final.url:
        print("Incorrect creds")
    else:
        print("Success")
```